# Spark google Bigquery table dataframe is returning no rows and is empty. However, printSchema returns the metadata information

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am connecting to the google bigquery table using spark-biquery-connector in the IntelliJ IDE. While reading the table and printing it, it doesn't show any records. However, metadata information is pulled from bigquery. Table emp has records present in it.

```
val spark= SparkSession.builder.appName("my first app")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()

val myDF = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "src\\main\\resources\\gcloud-rkg-cred.json").load("decoded-tribute-279515:gcp_test_db.emp")
val newDF = myDF.select("empid", "empname", "salary")
println(myDF.printSchema)
println(newDF.printSchema)
println(newDF.show)
```

myDF and newDf printSchemas returns the columns, but newDF.show only returns this  - ()

My **build.sbt** file is as below -

```
name := "myTestGCPProject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3"
ibraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.16.1"
```

Snapshot of schema and data of the table -

[image: schema of table]

[image: data from table]

After I tried with 0.17.0 as suggested by David in comments below - Following is the error I received.

```
20/07/23 11:17:43 INFO ComputeEngineCredentials: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
    root
     |-- empid: long (nullable = false)
     |-- empname: string (nullable = false)
     |-- location: string (nullable = false)
     |-- salary: long (nullable = false)
    root
     |-- empid: long (nullable = false)
     |-- empname: string (nullable = false)
     |-- salary: long (nullable = false)
    20/07/23 11:17:51 INFO DirectBigQueryRelation: Querying table decoded-tribute-279515.gcp_test_db.emp, parameters sent from Spark: requiredColumns=[empid,empname,salary], filters=[]
    20/07/23 11:17:51 INFO DirectBigQueryRelation: Going to read from decoded-tribute-279515.gcp_test_db.emp columns=[empid, empname, salary], filter=''
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 49
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 79
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 71
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 69
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_5_piece0 on raghav-VAIO:49977 in memory (size: 6.5 KB, free: 639.2 MB)
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 88
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 83
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 58
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on raghav-VAIO:49977 in memory (size: 20.8 KB, free: 639.2 MB)
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 14
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 62
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 87
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 76
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 8
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on raghav-VAIO:49977 in memory (size: 7.2 KB, free: 639.3 MB)
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 9
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 10
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 72
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on raghav-VAIO:49977 in memory (size: 4.5 KB, free: 639.3 MB)
    20/07/23 11:17:52 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 42
    [error] (run-main-0) com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    [error] com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:47)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1083)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1174)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:969)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:760)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:545)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [error] Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [error] Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:624)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.replace(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:572)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.replace(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:515)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ProtocolNegotiationHandler.fireProtocolNegotiationEvent(ProtocolNegotiators.java:767)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$WaitUntilActiveHandler.channelActive(ProtocolNegotiators.java:676)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:209)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1398)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:305)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:335)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ALPN unsupported. Is your classpath configured correctly? For Conscrypt, add the appropriate Conscrypt JAR to classpath and set the security provider. For Jetty-ALPN, see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-starting
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator$FailureWrapper.wrapSslEngine(JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:122)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.configureAndWrapEngine(JdkSslContext.java:360)
    [error]         at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.newEngine(JdkSslContext.java:335)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: Please make sure you use the spark-bigquery-with-dependencies artifact.

You don't need `println()` for those methods, please try

```
myDF.printSchema()
newDF.printSchema()
newDF.show()
```

Comment: No.. This didn't help much. At the end I'm getting this - and nothing after this from logs.

`20/07/22 12:11:06 INFO DirectBigQueryRelation: Querying table decoded-tribute-279515.gcp_test_db.emp, parameters sent from Spark: requiredColumns=[empid,empname,salary], filters=[]
20/07/22 12:11:06 INFO DirectBigQueryRelation: Going to read from decoded-tribute-279515.gcp_test_db.emp columns=[empid, empname, salary], filter=''
failed to find class org/conscrypt/CryptoUpcalls`

Comment: Which connector are you using? Can you please provide full path or artifact name?

Comment: I am using below connector -

`libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.16.1"`

Comment: Can you please upgrade to the latest version - 0.17.0 ?

Comment: I tried with 0.17.0 and it gave me another error - I have added the log snippet in the question. This comment section is too small for the several lines of log file. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Is it run on dataproc or on other Spark cluster (in house, EMR, etc.)?

Comment: I am running on my local machine  - Win7 + IntelliJ + Spark + SBT + BigQuery- spark.master=Local

Comment: And which Java version?

Comment: javac 1.8.0_261

Comment: Can you please open a bug in https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues with all the above data?

Comment: sure.. adding it.

Comment: submitted this - https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/216

Please let me know if anything else to add/modify in this. Thanks.